# Event.target refer to the child, not the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following nested div

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

In jQuery, I do

```
$('.parent').click(function (e) {
  e.target // this refers to .child instead of .parent
})
```

Is there a way to get the reference to `.parent` in this case withut doing something like `.closest()`?

Comment: I don't think so!! See this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/sx177uL2/)**. More understandable **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/sx177uL2/1/)**

Comment: I was so spoiled by jQuery's `this` that I forgot about `event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` instead of `e.target` and `this` as you may want to use jQuery methods on it.

```js
$('.parent').click(function(e) {
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```css
.parent {
  color: green;
}
.child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div class="child">Clild</div>
</div>
```

`$(this)` will always refer to the element on which the event has occurred.

Answer (score 3):

I was confused for a second why I couldn't simply use `$(this)` reference. I am using `Meteor` which binds `this` to a different object in an event callback. In that case, you can just use `event.currentTarget`, which I believe how jQuery binds `this` reference anyway.

Comment: This is the solution for me. Firefox gave me to correct target when using `event.target` but Chrome returned the child. `event.currentTarget` seems to return the real event trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `this`, it refers to element on which event has occurred.

```
$('.parent').click(function (e) {
    console.log(this);
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3p0ytmfz/)